# I cant create VPN Network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

I can't create new VPC. i delete all network.
When i press the button, nothing pass.

Can help me please
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ba6k.png)

Answer (score 0):

GCP is currently having issues with the "Create VPC network" button in the console when no networks exist.

You can still use [`gcloud compute networks create {name}`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/create) to create networks in this case though.